# Python Suds Soap Client Error - Bad Request Exception: (400, u'Bad Request')

Tags: python, soap, client, suds, bad-request

My SOAP URL is `202.46.201.237:82/MobilityService.svc?wsdl`

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from suds.client import Client
url_service = 'http://202.46.201.237:82/MobilityService.svc?wsdl'
client = Client(url_service,headers={'Content-Type':    'application/soap+xml', 'charset': 'utf-8'})

print client

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 GA  build: R699-20100913

Service ( MobilityService ) tns="http://tempuri.org/"
   Prefixes (3)
      ns0 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Models"
      ns1 = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
      ns2 = "http://tempuri.org/"
   Ports (1):
      (WSHttpBinding_IMobilityService)
         Methods (1):
           AddNomineeDetails(ns0:WebServiceInputView WebServiceInputView, )
         Types (4):
            ns0:WebServiceInputView
            ns1:char
            ns1:duration
            ns1:guid

result = client.factory.create('ns0:WebServiceInputView') 
result.MessageText = 'test'
result.MobileNo = '1234'
result = client.service.AddNomineeDetails(result)
```

I am getting an `Bad Request Exception: (400, u'Bad Request')` error. How do I fix that?

Comment: what is your question ?